# Animate UILabel text change inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, uilabel

I want to animate a `UILabel` inside a custom `UITableViewCell` when the text property changes.

I have the animation working fine, except the animation is firing every time the cell comes into view while scrolling and also when calling `[myTableView reloadData]`.

Using something as simple as

```
if (![myLabel.text isEqualToString:newText]) {
    // change myLabel.text with animation here. 
}
```

Does not work.

I understand why this is happening.
If I create a new cell each time, I could check if `myLabel.text` has a string, if so, is it different, and then apply the changes. However there are sometimes way too many cells to display.

When reusing cells, `myLabel.text` will almost always already have a string, and will almost always be different to what I want to set it to. So the above checks won't work. They will cause the animations to fire anyway.

The only way I can think of getting this to work is to create an array with the last known values in `myLabel.text` and do a comparison, but this list would be huge!

I have no idea where to begin solving this issue.

All I want is for `myLabel` to do a little flip/backgroundColor animation inside my subclassed `UITableViewCell` when the `text` property changes. The closest solutions I have found will cause *all* labels in the tableviewcell to run the animation.

I also can't check `myLabel.text` before giving it a string because it's always getting reused.

I'm starting to get the impression that this just can't be done.

Comment: Is this a `UITableViewCell` subclass?

Comment: Yes it is. Should I mention that in my question?

Comment: Yes, that should be made clear.

Comment: It's a little hard to say what you should do without knowing more about what exactly you want to see. If, for instance, you insert a new item into your array (in the middle somewhere) do you want all the labels below that one to animate, because the data is moving to a new cell (one further down), or only animate the cell you're adding? I think the solution is going to involve only updating the cells that change (using reloadRowsAtIndexPaths) instead of updating the whole table with reloadData.

Comment: The problem with updating only the cells that change is what if these cells were to have multiple labels? They would all be animated even if their text doesn't change.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not adding any new cells. Just changing the .text property of labels inside the cells. I may have to do this change outside of cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Can't you set some property on your cell like "should animate text change" when you need the animation? Or have a similar flag associated with the data for each row of your table. Then use *reloadRowsAtIndexPaths*.

Comment: It would still require tracking the previous value in myLabel.text and if it changes, set the property to YES. I've tried something similar, but because the cells were getting reused, there's no way to know if certain properties have been set already as nothing is retained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work by keeping track of the previous values held in `myLabel.text`.

I created an `NSMutableDictionary` on my viewController named `previousStrings`. With each key being an `indexPath.row`, and each value being a dictionary for that row.

Here's some code from inside `cellForRow` method.

```
NSMutableDictionary *strings;
// check to see if previousStrings already has a dictionary at key of indexPath.row
// if not, then create one.
if (![_previousStrings objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row]]) {
    strings = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
}
else {
    strings = [_previousStrings objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row]];
}
```

Then change `myLabel.text`

```
NSString *cellText = newTextString;
// If the new string is equal to the old string, just set the label without animation
// otherwise run animation and update the value inside the strings dictionary.
if ([strings[@"myLabel"] isEqualToString:newTextString]) {
    cell.myLabel.text = newTextString;
}
else {
    [cell.myLabel runTextChangeAnimationWithString:newTextString];
    [strings setObject:newTextString forKey:@"myLabel"];
}
```

After all that, at the end of `cellForRow` be sure to put the strings dict back into previousStrings

```
[_previousStrings setObject:strings forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row]];
```

I hope this makes sense for anyone else stumbling across the same issue.
Feel free to edit and ask questions if it's not clear enough.

This is how the dictionaries are structured. Numbers being the indexPaths of each cell.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you've subclassed `UITableViewCell`, you can override the default `prepareForReuse` method.  In this method, set your label's text property to `nil`.

```
- (void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];
    myLabel.text = nil;
}
```

Now:

```
if (myLabel.text && ![myLabel.text isEqualToString:newText]) {
    // change myLabel.text with animation here. 
}
```

Now the text should only animate if it's been changed from one text to a new text.

`prepareForReuse` is called on the cell by the tableview's `dequeueReusableCell` method.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, however, this isn't working quite the way I want it to. When I call [tableView reloadData] the animations aren't working. This is important as the only way I can reload the UILabels, is through updating the tableview, and the labels are set to nil every time this happens.

Comment: Might have it actually.

Answer (score 0):

```
#pragma mark - Timer Function
-(void)callAfteroneSecond_deals
{
    NSArray *indexes = [self.tbl_deals indexPathsForVisibleRows];
    MYTableViewCell *cell = (MYTableViewCell *)[_tbl_deals cellForRowAtIndexPath:index];


    cell.lbl_expiredtime.text=@"Hello";
    [cell.contentView bringSubviewToFront:cell.lbl_expiredtime];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would define a method on the custom cell like so:

```
   - (void) updateMyLabel: (NSString *)newText   {
        // If the new value is different than what is already set, 
        // and the label isn't nil, then trigger the animation
        if (self.myLabel.text && self.myLabel.text != newText)    {
            [UIView animateWithDuration...];
        }
        self.myLabel.text = newText;
    }
```

Then call that method in your tableView's cellForRowAtIndexPath. The tricky thing is that cellForRowAtIndexPath can get called multiple times as the user scrolls around, or as data changes (i.e. every time you call reloadData).

Comment: This I have tried. When scrolling, the cells are reused, and will almost always have myLabel initialised and holding some string in it's text property from the cell it's reusing. So this if statement, will always return yes.

Comment: Ah ok, so then as nhgrif mentioned, you just need to set the label text to nil in prepareForReuse in your custom cell class.

Comment: Ah yes, but every time [tableView reloadData] is called or the view is scrolled, all myLabel.text properties are set to nil. This means that the above if statement would always return NO. And no animations will trigger.